# Azure App Registration programmatically (Graph API)

Tags: azure, api, graph, registration

I'm trying to register an application in Azure programmatically. Most examples are targeting use of Azure Portal, which doesn't meet my requirements. Other examples assume that I have a registered app already and hold a bearer token to use for this operation. Again that doesn't meet my requirements.

In my scenario. I'm an Azure AD administrator, and I want to programmatically register **my first application**, without going to the Azure Portal. Since this is easily done via portal, I was hoping to do this in code as well (http/C# preferred). And as a step 2, *Add permissions* and *Grant admin consent* - again programmatically.

Eventually, I'm using the registered app's ClientId and ClientSecret to retrieve the bearer token and then query Graph API. (This part is working fine, when I make the app registration manually via Azure Portal)

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Unfortunately, not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Microsoft Graph API.

The API to use to create an app is: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_post_applications

To grant permission you can refer [`here`](https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2016/10/07/application-permission-with-v2-endpoint-and-microsoft-graph/)

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply.

This method requires a bearer token? Where does that come from then?

"Other examples assume that I have a registered app already to use for this operation and again that doesn't meet my requirements."